# Is it possible to generate permutations of a list of numbers, adding a number one by one?

Tags: sequence, permutation

I am trying to make a program that computes the number of permutations of a series of numbers, such that the numbers in the permutation alternate from increasing to decreasing. 
For example, given the series 1, 2, ..., n with n = 4, a permutation that I am looking for would be for example 1423, as 4>1, 2<4, 3>2.

Now I have already created the part of my program that checks if the permutation is correct, but I have found that generating all the permutations in the normal way (by swapping numbers around) takes too much time.
That's why I'm wondering if there is a way to generate all the permutations of the given list, adding a number one by one.

For example, it would start with 1, then it would add 2 to the list, to get 1-2. 1-2 would then be checked to see if the sequence does conform to the rule of increasing/decreasing. As it does conform, 3 would then be added, giving 1-2-3. 1-2-3 is then checked, which doesn't conform. So we would go back to 1, now adding 3 instead of 2, giving 1-3 etc.

I am using C.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the built in `itertools`

```
from itertools import permutations
print(list(permutations([1,2,3,4])))
```

will print all permutations of 1,2,3 and 4 in a list of tuples.

You can find more information about itertools.permutations at [itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: Thank you. However, I don't think this is available in C, is it?

Comment: oh wait, makes sense, also u want to add numbers 1 by 1.